# How does a computer get info about a connected monitor?

Tags: display, hdmi, vga, dvi, computer-architecture

How does it get info, max resolution etc about it, for HDMI i could think of CEC, but what about VGA/DVI etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Display Data Channel (DDC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel)

[Extended Display Identification Data (EDID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data)